2024 United States Eucharistic Congress Meetup?
If anybody who uses Christianity Stackexchange and is attending the National Eucharistic Congress in Indianapolis, it'd be awesome to have a meet-up when we get there!  We might be able to plug the site a little bit too, which wouldn't be a terrible thing.
Ping me on chat if you want to be discrete or voice your ideas here (if you do think this is a bad idea)
If you think this is too Catholic or too USA centric, imagine it's a Star Wars convention meetup posted on scifi.SE in Italy and you're a Peruvian Trekkie. I'd love to see more people posting on meta about ways to promote the site in any capacity.

I’m voting to close this question because not particularity relevant anymore
